# Spring data repository mapped one to one findByObject not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have an entity A which has a one to one mapping with with entity B. I want to find a row in entity A using findByObject.

Here is my entity which has a one to one relation with BankUser:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "str_filter_rule")
public class STRFilterRule extends STRRule {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
private Long id;

@OneToOne
private BankUser bankUser;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private TransactionDeviation transactionDeviation;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private TransactionActivity transactionActivity;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private AccountActivity accountActivity;

public STRFilterRule() {
    super();
}

public STRFilterRule(BankUser bankUser, TransactionDeviation transactionDeviation, TransactionActivity transactionActivity,
        AccountActivity accountActivity) {
    super();
    this.bankUser = bankUser;
    this.transactionDeviation = transactionDeviation;
    this.transactionActivity = transactionActivity;
    this.accountActivity = accountActivity;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public BankUser getBankUser() {
    return bankUser;
}

public void setBankUser(BankUser bankUser) {
    this.bankUser = bankUser;
}

public TransactionDeviation getTransactionDeviation() {
    return transactionDeviation;
}

public void setTransactionDeviation(TransactionDeviation transactionDeviation) {
    this.transactionDeviation = transactionDeviation;
}

public TransactionActivity getTransactionActivity() {
    return transactionActivity;
}

public void setTransactionActivity(TransactionActivity transactionActivity) {
    this.transactionActivity = transactionActivity;
}

public AccountActivity getAccountActivity() {
    return accountActivity;
}

public void setAccountActivity(AccountActivity accountActivity) {
    this.accountActivity = accountActivity;
}
```

}

Now in my repository there is a method to get List of STRFilterRules

```
@Repository
public interface STRFilterRuleRepository extends    CrudRepository<STRFilterRule, Long> {

List<STRFilterRule> findByBankUser(BankUser bankuser);
}
```

Now while running the program my console gives following error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener   instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'STRSettingController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'strFilterRuleServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.lftechnology.warehouse.suspicioustransaction.repository.STRFilterRuleRepository com.lftechnology.warehouse.suspicioustransaction.service.impl.StrFilterRuleServiceImpl.strFilterRuleRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'STRFilterRuleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'strFilterRuleServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.lftechnology.warehouse.suspicioustransaction.repository.STRFilterRuleRepository com.lftechnology.warehouse.suspicioustransaction.service.impl.StrFilterRuleServiceImpl.strFilterRuleRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'STRFilterRuleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:512)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:615)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.lftechnology.warehouse.suspicioustransaction.repository.STRFilterRuleRepository com.lftechnology.warehouse.suspicioustransaction.service.impl.StrFilterRuleServiceImpl.strFilterRuleRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'STRFilterRuleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'STRFilterRuleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1069)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.isAlreadyFetched(QueryUtils.java:558)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:473)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:199)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:146)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:86)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:44)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:110)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:230)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:64)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:408)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 47 more
```

Comment: It is being autowired in service. But when I remove the above method from repository there are no errors.

Comment: You configure a OneToOne and return a list. EIther the List or the OneToOne is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below the code, and this will hold all the parent object under **BankUser**

```
@Repository
public interface STRFilterRuleRepository extends    CrudRepository<STRFilterRule, Long> {

STRFilterRule findById(long id);
}
```

Comment: one to one relationship never return result as List in either side of the relationship. Why are you expecting the result will be in List? Why are you getting null pointer exception? Can you send the code piece where do you do autowiring of the repo in your service or controller side

Answer (score 0):

Since your ignoring my comment.
There's a OneToOne mapping between STRFilterRule and BankUser, so there can't be a return type List. Either change the mapping or the return type.

Example for changing the return type.

```
@Repository
public interface STRFilterRuleRepository extends    CrudRepository<STRFilterRule, Long> {

    STRFilterRule findByBankUser(BankUser bankuser);
}
```